# django 1.11 - how to get radio dynamic name in view?

Tags: django, templates, view, radio-button

this's my template code, I don't know how to get the input name in `view.py`, What should I do ?

```html
{% for visitor in visitors %}
<label class="btn btn-secondary {% if visitor.is_vip == True %}active{% endif %}">
 <input type="radio" name="{{visitor.face_id}}" value="vip" {% if visitor.is_vip == True %}checked{% endif %}> VIP
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary {% if visitor.is_black == True %}active{% endif %}">
 <input type="radio" name="{{visitor.face_id}}" value="black" {% if visitor.is_black == True %}checked{% endif %} > Black
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary {% if visitor.is_vip != True and visitor.is_black != True %}active{% endif %}"> 
 <input type="radio" name="{{visitor.face_id}}" value="guest" {% if visitor.is_vip != True and visitor.is_black != True %}checked{% endif %} > Guest
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you could use in the view:

```
request.POST.get('name_of_your_input')
```